# How to perform Simple Arithmetic Operations using array and functions in C

Tags: c

I just made a program using array, function, etc in C language, but it's not showing accurate results in multiplication, sub and division. Maybe the formula to perform operations are wrong. Please help to complete this program and here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void SimpleArithematic();

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    SimpleArithematic();
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void SimpleArithematic()
{
    char ch;
    int n;
    long num=0,i,sum[100];
    printf("Which Operation you want to perform: +,-,*,/?\n");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    printf("Input Total Inputs: \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Input Numbers \n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter Number %d: \n",i+1);
        scanf("%ld",&sum[i]);
    }
    switch(ch)
    {
        case '+':
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                num=num+sum[i];
            printf("Addition: %ld",num);
            break;
        case '-':
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                num=num-sum[i];
            }
            printf("Subtraction: %ld",num);
            break;
        case'*':
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                sum[i]=sum[i]*num;
            printf("Multiplication: %ld",num);
            break;
        case'/':
            for(i=0;i<n;i++)
                num=num/sum[i];
            printf("Division: %ld",num);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid Input!!");
    }
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPpwi.png)

Comment: Can you please show some sample input, and the actual and expected output?

Comment: while a sum of arbitrary numbers should be initialized at zero, a product of arbitrary numbers should be initialized at one. A difference and a quotient of arbitrary numbers makes little sense to me (difference of a, b and c is (a-b)-c or a-(b-c) or other ? . (hence, we need what you think is the *expected* output)

Answer (score 1):

You are dividing two `long` variables:

```
num=num/sum[i];
```

If `num` is less than `sum[i]`, your result `num` will be zero, since the decimal places are truncated in integer divisions.

Anyways, `num` is initialized to be `0`, so whatever you divide it with will give you `0` again.

Also for your multiplication, you probably had a typo:

```
sum[i]=sum[i]*num;
```

Yet again, since `num` is initialized to be `0`, whatever you multiply it with will give you `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The loops are all starting with `num = 0` and then doing the operation on all the input numbers.  This happens to work with addition because `0 + x = x` (the identity function), but it doesn't work for the rest. `0 - x = -x`, `0 / x = 0`, and `0 * x = 0`.

Instead, set `num = sum[0]` and loop starting at `i = 1`.

This is in addition to the problems pointed out in the other answers.

---

As a side note, I'd recommend not naming anything but loop variables things like `n`. It's hard to understand what they mean and they're very hard to search for. Call it `num_sum` to indicate that its the number of things in `sum`. (`sum` is a bad name, too, since it's not the sums. It should be called `inputs` because it's the inputs).

Also, initialize loop variables (ie. `i`) in place. This makes the code easier to ready by avoiding great blocks of variable initializers at the top of the code. This style is a hold over from Ye Olden Days when all variables had to be declared at the start of the function. And it avoids the hard to debug case of the value of a local variable being retained in its next use. For example...

```
int i;

for( i = 0; i < blah; i++ ) {
    ...
}

...later on...

for( i; i < blah; i++ ) {
    ...
}
```

Because `i` retains its value from the previous loop, you will not be warned about your mistake.